# for loop in python to connect the data from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge file(20,000 rows) with 2 columns (id and value). Some ids have different value. I want to write a for loop to give me all values for ids.

By the way I am using pandas and importing the data as data frame.

for example:
 The file is:

```
id  value 
a    2
a    3
b    2
c    4
b    5
```

I want the result to be like:

```
a 2,3
b 2,5
c 4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:
you want a list of values

```
df.groupby('id').value.apply(list)

id
a    [2, 3]
b    [2, 5]
c       [4]
Name: value, dtype: object
```

if you want strings... this is @jezrael's answer, just modified to my tastes

```
df.astype(str).groupby('id').value.apply(','.join)

id
a    2,3
b    2,5
c      4
Name: value, dtype: object
```

---

***experimental `numpy` solution***

```
u, i = np.unique(df.id.values, return_inverse=True)
g = np.arange(len(u))[:, None] == i

def slc(r):
    return df.value.values[r].tolist()

pd.Series(list(map(slc, g)), u)

a    [2, 3]
b    [2, 5]
c       [4]
dtype: object
```

for strings

```
u, i = np.unique(df.id.values, return_inverse=True)
g = np.arange(len(u))[:, None] == i

def slc(r):
    return ','.join(map(str, df.value.values[r].tolist()))

pd.Series(list(map(slc, g)), u)

a    2,3
b    2,5
c      4
dtype: object
```

---

***timing***

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO")
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.random.choice(L, N), 
                   'value': np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
```

***code***

```
def pir1(df):
    return df.astype(str).groupby('id').value.apply(','.join)

def pir2(df):
    u, i = np.unique(df.id.values, return_inverse=True)
    g = np.arange(len(u))[:, None] == i

    def slc(r):
        return ','.join(map(str, df.value.values[r].tolist()))

    return pd.Series(list(map(slc, g)), u, name='value')

def pir3(df):
    return df.groupby('id').value.apply(list)

def pir4(df):
    u, i = np.unique(df.id.values, return_inverse=True)
    g = np.arange(len(u))[:, None] == i

    def slc(r):
        return df.value.values[r].tolist()

    return pd.Series(list(map(slc, g)), u, name='value')

def jez1(df):
    return df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
```

***results***
**Note:** `pir1` and `pir2` are string results.  `pir3` and `pir4` are list results.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` `join`. Obviously if numeric column `value` is necessary cast to `string`:

```
print (df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index())
  id value
0  a   2,3
1  b   2,5
2  c     4
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO")
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.random.choice(L, N), 
                   'value': np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
#[1000000 rows x 2 columns]                   
print (df)

In [84]: %timeit (df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index())
1 loop, best of 3: 1.46 s per loop

In [85]: %timeit (df.astype(str).groupby('id').value.apply(','.join).reset_index())
1 loop, best of 3: 1.83 s per loop
```

Comment: If need faster solution, need lambda with join. see update of my answer.